# concat column names with string inside a string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, concatenation

I am trying to create a pretty column to display but I cannot get a space or hyphen to work. I want the column to display like

Jun-2014 or Jun 2014  but I get errors when I try to insert it the normal way due to the query already being inside a string.

Here is the part I am having trouble with:

```
(LEFT(DATENAME(month, leadtime),3) + " " + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(year, leadtime))) as leadmonth
```

And here is the rest of the query for context:

```
set @query = 'SELECT name AS "Lead Source",' + @cols + '
from 
(
SELECT d.name, COUNT(u.lead_source_id) AS totalLeads, + "["+ (LEFT(DATENAME(month, leadtime),3) + " " + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(year, leadtime)))+"] as leadmonth" +
FROM DI_TrackingDB.dbo.userleads u
INNER JOIN GSPremiumServices.dbo.supplier_product_lead_source_def d ON d.lead_source_id = u.lead_source_id
WHERE vend_id = 355135
    AND u.lead_source_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY u.lead_source_id, d.name, DATENAME(month, leadtime), DATEPART(year, leadtime), Convert(varchar(7), leadtime, 126)
) x
pivot 
(
max(totalLeads)
for leadmonth in (' + @cols + ')
) p '
```

Please keep in mind I am setting `@query` so I am already inside of a string. 
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was quite simple. Not sure if people didn't quite understand my initial question but the answer was to use two `'` on either side of the inner string. Below is the final version of the code that works.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(monthyear)
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT (LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, month_start),3)+ '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YEAR, month_start))) AS monthyear, month_start
          FROM dbo.mo_vendor_month WITH(NOLOCK)
          WHERE vend_id = #arguments.prospectId#
          AND month_start >= '#startDate#'
         )alertsMonths
        ORDER BY month_start ASC
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
     ,1,1,'')

    SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + '
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT total_unique_leads,(LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, month_start),3)+ ''-'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YEAR, month_start))) AS monthyear
        FROM dbo.mo_vendor_month
        WHERE vend_id = #arguments.prospectId#
        AND month_start >= ''#startDate#''
        GROUP BY month_start, total_unique_leads
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
        max(total_unique_leads)
        FOR monthyear IN (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put square brackets around the field name you're constructing, like this:

```
"[" + (LEFT(DATENAME(month, leadtime),3) + " " + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(year, leadtime))) + "] as leadmonth"
```

I would also be ready to handle any single quotes or double quotes that might occur (by escaping them as needed when building your string). Other than that, enclosing a field name in square brackets allows you to use characters that normally would not be allowed in an identifier's name.

Comment: That seems to work by itself if I weren't already inside of a string. But adding that into the full query results in `incorrect syntax near the keyword FROM`  I edited my post above to reflect the change.

Comment: Rather than executing `@query`, just `print` it, and copy the resulting message to a new window and look to make sure your strings are escaped correctly -- likely your quotes are the culprit... happens to us all when we a string in a string.  And use two ' not a ".